# Install Boto3 AWS EMR Failed attempting to download bootstrap action

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr

I am trying to create my cluster using bootstrap actions option (which install boto3 on all nodes), but getting always **Master instance failed attempting to download bootstrap action 1 file from S3**

my bootstrapfile:
`sudo pip install boto3`

Command to create cluster :

`aws emr create-cluster --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Hue Name=Mahout Name=Pig Name=Tez --ec2-attributes "{\"KeyName\":\"key-ec2\",\"InstanceProfile\":\"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole\",\"SubnetId\":\"subnet-49ad9733\",\"EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup\":\"sg-009d9df2b7b6b1302\",\"EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup\":\"sg-0149cdd6586fe6db5\"}" --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --enable-debugging --release-label emr-5.30.1 --log-uri "s3n://aws-logs-447793603558-us-east-2/elasticmapreduce/" --name "MyCluster" --instance-groups "[{\"InstanceCount\":1,\"EbsConfiguration\":{\"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs\":[{\"VolumeSpecification\":{\"SizeInGB\":32,\"VolumeType\":\"gp2\"},\"VolumesPerInstance\":1}]},\"InstanceGroupType\":\"MASTER\",\"InstanceType\":\"m4.large\",\"Name\":\"Master Instance Group\"},{\"InstanceCount\":2,\"EbsConfiguration\":{\"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs\":[{\"VolumeSpecification\":{\"SizeInGB\":32,\"VolumeType\":\"gp2\"},\"VolumesPerInstance\":1}]},\"InstanceGroupType\":\"CORE\",\"InstanceType\":\"m4.large\",\"Name\":\"Core Instance Group\"}]" --scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION --region us-east-2 --bootstrap-action Path=s3://calculsdistribues/bootstrap-emr.sh`

I already created successfuly cluster without the bootstrap-action option.

What is the mistake here ? how my bootstrap file should looks like ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking in the logs, I found this error :
`The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request`

The problem was that S3 bucket was created in a region and the cluster was created in another region.

I just created the cluster in the same region and it's worked.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have given read access to s3 bucket where your bootstrap script is present for the Instace profile `"InstanceProfile\":\"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`